# How does Next.js basePath works for images?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to add a `basePath` to my `next.config.js`, it works well for the website content. But all the images are broken.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/my-sub-url',
  assetPrefix: '/my-sub-url/'
}
```

I also tried adding all the image path to something like this:

```
src="/my-sub-url/image.jpg"
```

And I also tried created a `my-sub-url` folder in my `public` folder, but still no luck.

My codes and images are all in my GitHub private project, and I'm deploying using Vercel.com. Currently I'm in Next.js v10 canary.

Is this because I host my images in GitHub? Or any other settings that I've missed out on? Don't seem to be find anything in Vercel/Next.js docs and other online places.

Comment: Where are the images located within your Next.js app? Are you serving them from the `public/` folder?

Comment: @juliomalves yup they are all in `public/`

Answer (score 1):

Since the *basePath* property in next.config.js effectively changes all other links, and if the use case is limited only to images being loaded from the *public/* folder or some directory in it. I found some solution which can avoid rewriting all src attributes of Image elements in the project.

```js
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    basePath:"/your-base-path",
    images:{
        loader:"custom",
        loaderFile:"/path/to/custom-image-loader.js",
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

```js
//custom-image-loader.js

import { basePath } from "../next.config";
import path from "path";


export default function myImageLoader({src,width}) {
  if( basePath && path.isAbsolute(src) ){
    return `${basePath}${src}?width=${width}`;
  }
  return `${src}?width=${width}`;
}
```

After adding this to your project. Mostly all image src attributes which are **not absolute URLs** (external links) should be accessible without having to add basePath to each Image component.

Answer (score 0):

The official Next.js documentation states that basePath is needed to be explicitly coded in the Images[Src] attribute.

So, if you setup your basePath in the next.config.js, like this:

```
      /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
    basePath: '/absproxy/3000',
    assetPrefix: '/absproxy/3000',
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    trailingSlash: true,
    async rewrites() {
        return [
        {
            source: '/images/:path*',
            destination: '/absproxy/3000/images/:path*', // The :path parameter isn't used here so will be automatically passed in the query
        },
        ]
    },
    images: {
        path: '/absproxy/3000/_next/image',
    },
    }

    module.exports = nextConfig
```

Then I have my flower.jpg located in

> {my_project_path}/public/images/flower.jpg

Here we have 3 ways to apply the basePath in your Image component:

1. Hard-coding

   ```
   import Head from 'next/head';
   import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
   import Link from 'next/link';
   import Image from 'next/image'; 

   export default function Home() {
       return (
           <div className={styles.container}>
           <Head>
               <title>Create Next App</title>
               <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
           </Head>
           <main>
               <Image
               src='/absproxy/3000/images/flower.jpg'// Route of the image file
               height={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
               width={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
               alt="Your Name"
               />
           </main>
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```
2. Import the image file as variable ({flower}):

> import flower from '../public/images/flower.jpg'

then use as the Image[src] attribute:

```
    import Head from 'next/head';
    import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import Image from 'next/image';
    import flower from '../public/images/flower.jpg'
    export default function Home() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <main>
                <Image
                src={flower}// Route of the image file
                height={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
                width={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
                alt="Your Name"
                />
            </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

3. Import the

> basePath

variable from next.config.js, and then concatenate the relative path of the static image file, and then apply in the src attribute of the image component.

> src={`${basePath}/images/flower.jpg`}

```
        import Head from 'next/head';
    import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import Image from 'next/image';

    import { basePath } from '../next.config';

    export default function Home() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <main>
                <Image
                src={`${basePath}/images/flower.jpg`}// Route of the image file
                height={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
                width={144} // Desired size with correct aspect ratio
                alt="Your Name"
                />
            </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
```